# React site sometimes not going full width of screen on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

So I am designing a portfolio site for myself and I am using react-scroll along with react-animate-on-scroll on the site. Sometimes (usually when you click the portfolio nav link and then the github nav link) the site doesn't scroll all the way down to the github section and you can zoom out and it will look like this picture (also only happens on mobile views):

[image]

As soon as you click on anything, it will go back to full width... You can examine the site's behavior here: https://jorrharris-website.herokuapp.com/

It also doesn't even happen when I reload the page, usually only happens when i take these steps:
1. Open mobile device view in chrome tools
2. expand the navbar and click the portfolio link
3. expand the navbar again and click the github link
(It will stop scrolling before the github page and then you can zoom out and see the screen is not the full width)

I've been trying to figure out why this is happening for a couple days now, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can only reproduce the problem sometimes. Try hiding the x-axis overflow in CSS like this:

```
html, body{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: U saved me so much time. Thanks